# heaviest edge with lowest weight between all paths

Tags: graph, shortest-path, weighted, network-flow

Given a graph with n vertices, indirect,weighted, with no negative cycles and two nodes s,t - to find a path from s to t that the heaviest edge in the path have the lightest weight between all paths from s to t.

one solution I thought about to run BFS from s, find some path between s to t, save the heaviest edge in the path, delete it, and do it at most |E| times.
the complexity is O(|V| + |E|)*E).
I'm looking for another solution that maybe involves network flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea would be to remove all edges, then add them back in ascending order until s and t are connected (which you can do quickly by keeping track of which island each node belongs to each iteration).  Finally, do BFS.

Comment: in my understanding this solution complexity is same as my solution, O(VE + E^2). I thought maybe there is better solution but maybe i'm wrong.. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @GalCohen: It should just be O(V+E) using a [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to keep track of islands